# json formatting datetime, date and time

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have a Class with the following

```
class MyClass {

    private Date datetime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2018-01-01 11:32:15");

    private Time time = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis());

    private Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Gson**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(myClass));

Gson gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
System.out.println(gsonBuilder.toJson(myClass));
```

I get

```
{"datetime":"Jan 1, 2018 11:32:15 AM","time":"04:51:23 PM","date":"Jan 1, 2018 4:51:23 PM"}

{"datetime":"2018-01-01 11:32:15","time":"04:51:23 PM","date":"2018-01-01 16:51:23"}
```

**Jackson**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(myClass));

mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(myClass));
```

I get

```
{"datetime":1514806335000,"time":"17:01:18","date":1514826078776}

{"datetime":"2018-01-01T11:32:15.000+0000","time":"17:13:52","date":"2018-01-01T17:13:52.224+0000"}
```

How can I get

```
{"datetime":"2018-01-01 11:32:15","time":"16:51:23","date":"2018-01-01"}
```

I am not tied to any library so if there is a more appropriate JSON library that can do the job, please comment.

Comment: A little stupid way, use gson and write your own DateWrapper and override toString().

Answer (score 2):

With Jackson, annotate your `dateTime` and `date` fields with

```
@JsonFormat
  (shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Snap! Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

Using Jackson you can annotate each Field

```
class MyClass {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public Date datetime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2018-01-01 11:32:15");

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "HH:mm:ss")
    public Time time = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis());

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    public Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

    MyClass() throws ParseException { }

}

MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(myClass));
```

Gives you

```
{"datetime":"2018-01-01 11:32:15","time":"17:21:22","date":"2018-01-01"}
```